# unreadable fields in VisualFoxPro

Tags: c#, sql, visual-foxpro

I am trying to connect my c# application to visualFoxPro database. After getting data from foxpro table I will put it in SQL Server on realtime basis.

In each table of Foxpro there is unique fields (for example `UID` and `station` in given snapshot), which is not readable. I Don't know it is encrypted or it is some format, I am attaching screen shot also.

I have tried opening table in DBFViwer and it shows unreadable character too.
I need to know how to get thosese unreadable values, because they are important for me.

[image: Snapshot of Table]

Comment: How did you get the data out? You might need foxpro to export it to get sensible dats if you dont have the odbc reader for it

Comment: I am using microsoft OLEDB driver (VFPOLEDB.) for getting data from foxpro.

Comment: It does seem odd then it doesnt read it. Normally id expect something like that when using a dbase drive on a foxpro file.. What does the data look like in foxpro?

Comment: i dont have Foxpro installed, i have some Point of Sale installed which is using foxPro database. i have tried to download foxpro software but i cant find it. When i use ODBC drivers i get exception "table is in unknown format" thats why i am using VFOLEDB.

Comment: Foxpro was never free, microsoft also killed it off i think, but still you cant get it free.  Did you get the driver from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839  it also maybe that you need exactly the right version.

Comment: Yes i got driver from the link you provided. plus i ran queries which involves inner join and group by . there quires shows correct result. The problem is just that these fields are not human readable. DBFviwer opens all kind of Foxpro and visual foxpro databse regardless of there versions.

Comment: Without a copy of foxpro i think you might be a little challenged. While my foxpro is rusty, im fairly sure they didnt have a field type uid, only ints. If you have msdn subscription you can probably get foxpro from it

Comment: I have just checked in FoxPro 9.0 SP2, those fields are still same, not readable.

Comment: Well that is weird. Its been a good number of years.. Its interesting that your queries work as expected - I'm guessing those fields aren't for us humans to understand.

Comment: here is snapshot of my query and result, http://i.stack.imgur.com/qFODT.png

Comment: What is the type of the unreadable field?

Comment: OK, so it definitely works we just cant read it - why is UID needing to be seen? it wouldn't mean anything to anything other than the FoxPro db

Comment: Actually all fields which are not readable are primary keys. I am developing a central database using MSSQL where data from all Point of Sales will be collected, there for these fields are very important.

Comment: Can you post a samplel of the actual foxpro files for me to download and look at?

Comment: What you're describing is very strange. VFP doesn't have any native encryption. While there are ways to encrypt VFP data, it seems really unlikely that someone would have encrypted only the PK fields. Do you have the VFP source code? There might be a clue there. If not, is there a vertical app, that is, not custom? If the company it came from isn't around anymore, there might still be someone familiar with the product.

Comment: i am adding link to sample, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ceqbQ3TIwvOHl1Nk9FWkhGTFk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason behind the unreadable values.

in code i found they were converting number into Binary and appended it with some character, which become unreadable for human eyes:-

```
BINTOC(71965)+'078'
```

i reversed removed last 3 characters and used CTOBIN to get back orignal number.

Answer (score 0):

We have a number of VB.ASP applications which successfully access data on an on-going basis from an active Legacy Foxpro application's data tables.

We utilize the VFP Connection string for Free Tables:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-visual-foxpro-odbc-driver/

This enables us to set up a Connection to the table(s) and run an SQL Query string (using VFP SQL Query syntax).

In that way, all of the data is acquired for the VB.ASP application to use as needed.

NOTE - We have no way of knowing if your data were encrypted in some way or not.
If it were encrypted, then you would need to determine how it were done.
You would then retrieve the encrypted data as described above and then need to decrypt it on your own within your application.